# How to count the total ranges in my VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I was given an excel file, with the task of counting the total amount of "ranges" in the code, Example: Range("ReComp"). The Main worksheet has over 1453 ranges, but I want to know how many are actually being used in the script.

Comment: you will have to go through the script and count the range references manually

Comment: Copy the code to Notepad++ and do a serch all for range(" then you will get all lines with Range as the Result

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried using the VBIDE objects before, so this may be able to be improved by someone more experienced.  It should give you a good start anyway:

```
Sub test()
    'Needs a reference to Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

    Set VBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    Dim nme As Name
    Dim lineNo As Long
    Dim nmeUsed As Boolean
    Dim numUsed As Long

    numUsed = 0
    For Each nme In ThisWorkbook.Names
        nmeUsed = False
        For lineNo = 1 To CodeMod.CountOfLines
            If InStr(CodeMod.Lines(lineNo, lineNo), "Range(""" & nme.Name & """") > 0 Then
                nmeUsed = True
                numUsed = numUsed + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If nmeUsed Then
            Debug.Print nme.Name & " used"
        Else
            Debug.Print nme.Name & " not used"
        End If
    Next
    'Used for testing
    'MsgBox Range("xxx").Address
    'MsgBox Range("yyy").Address
    MsgBox numUsed & " range names were used out of the " & _
           ThisWorkbook.Names.Count & " total"
End Sub
```

Comment: very nice .... upvote  .... can be improved by dumping data into a blank worksheet

Comment: @jsotola Do you mean the stuff I `Debug.Print`ed?  If so, I guess that could be a nice little table:  Name, RefersTo, Scope, UsedInCodeSomewhere.

Comment: @jsotola P.S. If you want to play with that code and expand it (e.g. I'm not sure whether just searching `ThisWorkbook.Names` is sufficient, or whether  worksheet-scoped names only appearing in the relevant Worksheet.Names collection, and it could also be improved by looping through all code modules instead of just "Module1") then please do so.  I won't have time to look at it in any real detail for a while.  If you **do** expand on it, post it as your own answer and ping me to delete my answer.  (I'm quite happy to do so.)

Comment: This is much better than moving the code to NotePad++. Upvote for you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Either Notepad++ or just straight up copying your code into word. Then do a find for something like `range(` and you should get a hit count

Comment: Two problems: 1) the hit count will give multiple "counts" for multiple occurrences of the same range, and 2) it is going to be very hard to include `Range("ReComp")` while excluding `Range("R1:T20")`.

Comment: Decent point. I mean I have a complicated VBA example that could do it, but it involved exporting the VBA project into a text file and then having another VBA (or any other high-level language) read the file and count the unique hits

Comment: Come to think of it... I like your code better

Comment: Yeah, I did think (before I played with VBIDE) that the code could just be exported to a `.bas` file, then read back in and searched that way, i.e. create the list of names, then loop through the exported code file reading each line and doing the `Instr` for each name in the list, and ticking the names off once found.  The most dangerous part of this is going to be if the code has something like `If x = 5 Then rngNme = "ABC" Else rngNme = "XYZ"` followed by some code using `Range(rngNme)`.  No amount of programatical searching is going to pick up the use of both "ABC" and "XYZ" in that case.